# How can we allow an NFT to only be be traded on OpenSea and make direct transfer not possible?

Tags: nft, opensea

How to Stop Direct Transfer of  NFT only Trade of NFT on opensea should be available ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenSea's `OperatorFilterRegistry` to block transfers to trading platforms without trading fees.
[Here](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/operator-filter-registry/blob/main/src/example/RevokableExampleERC721.sol) is an example for an ERC-721 token.

Note that this is not a foolproof mechanism and NFT owners can always trade peer-to-peer or use unlisted exchanges.
You should also trust OpenSea not to ban competing trading platforms or even users. Using the `OperatorFilterRegistry` will make your NFTs vulnerable to censorship and will reduce the initial sale value of your NFTs.